# Was it ethically sound to state the way a coworker referred to someone as going against company values?

Tags: united-states, ethics, performance-reviews, sexism

## Background

There is a coworker at work who is an amazing coworker in terms of the job.  He aids as many people he can in any way he can in addition to being a quick problem solver.  When asked to comment about him during a performance review, I stated as such.

In the section where it states "going against company values", I stated that in a (presumably) fit of frustration, he referred to someone as a "girl". One of the values is "Respect". The comment was not made directly to the woman, but rather in reference when talking with another male colleague.  She was in her 50's and works in Information Security. I also stipulated to not hold that against him because I shared his frustration about the matter.  However, that specific terminology seemed questionable to me.  There is a part of me that feels I overreacted and it may have been an unethical example of abusing the "going against company values" section.  However, given the circumstances of the situation above, I am not sure.

## Question

Is including the way a coworker referred to a woman as a "girl"  reasonable to put in the section of an evaluation called "going against company values"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right, it's not nice to call a grown woman "girl". It's not respectful.

Technically, you are right to put it in there.

However, you should think about whether that is the world you want to live in: where every little one-time occurrence of going against the rules is immediately written down and filed with HR.

You said yourself, the person only did it because they were frustrated. Do you really want whatever you say in a moment of frustration being recorded and used against you later?

If there is something that is continuing on, then it would be right to say something. In this case, to me it looks like you only remembered this incident because you were asked to find something. Sometimes, leaving a box blank is perfectly acceptable. You don't *have* to find something bad about a colleague just because there is a question in a questionnaire.

Comment: I agree with this answer. We should not be making judgement about people's value system based on a single utterance when they are under stress. This is a question about ethics, so you should weight up potential outcomes. You mention the event: HR fires the person for offensive behaviour. You get reprimanded for not reporting it. You don't mention it, and someone that (very?) ocassionally uses the wrong word doesn't get fired. (And for those that doubt HR would be so extreme... don't be naive)

Answer (score 4):

Tjeez, is that a thing in the united states nowadays, in addition to managers, peers have to evaluate each other as well? And these evaluations go in such detail that you are encouraged to find little things about each other to rat on? Don't see how that fosters a nice working environment.

But anyway, back to your question. Yes, it is (slightly) disrespectful to refer to a grown woman as a girl and it's probably against company policy if the company wants be non-sexist and inclusive. However it is such a little thing, if it was only a one-time-occurence, said in frustration and behind the back of person in question. So yes, in my opinion it was wrong and unethical of you to include this incident in the performance review. Lets hope no one saw and mentioned in your performance review that you oggled that nice intern a few seconds longer than appropriate or some other small faux pas.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go against the common theme in the answers so far.

You absolutely did the right thing; Respect is not just something you show when the person in question is witness to it, it includes how you talk about that person with others. The instance you describe was definitely disrespect as your colleague referred to another colleague as a child (it would be just as disrespectful to refer to someone as "the boy").

While you were witness to one instance of disrespect (in frustration or not), others may have witnessed other individual instances themselves. If everyone went "Oh it's just one instance, no biggy" you end up with it building until someone asks the question "How did no-one notice?"

If it truly is one instance, then HR will likely monitor but not say anything. If it's something that pops up every year or multiple times a year, then something will be said.

Comment: But then, correcting the behavior right away, or perhaps a day later when you can be alone with that person, is usually far more effective than mentioning it a few months later in a yearly review.

Comment: I agree that raising it personally is always a good approach, but there's various reasons why someone might not. Even if it was raised immediately, it should be included in the review in case there is a trend.